# MongoDB CSV Export => RethinkDB CSV Import Error

Tags: mongodb, csv, import, rethinkdb

I first exported data from MongoDB using mongoexport using the code below:-

```
mongoexport --host 192.168.16.130 --db dbname --collection transaction --out out.csv
```

Then I tried to import this CSV file to RethinkDB but I always get this error :-

```
rethinkdb import -f out.csv --format csv --table test.data
```

ERROR
"no primary key specified, using default primary key when creating table
[                                        ]   0% 
0 rows imported in 1 table
Error: File '/home/akashyap/out.csv' line 6 has an inconsistent number of columns
In file: /home/akashyap/out.csv
Errors occurred during import"

Is there any problem with the format of CSV file? The same problem is happening with JSON file too.

Comment: rethinkdb is it a nosql db  it is showing error which is saying there is varaiation in the schema

Comment: Can you post a sample of your CSV?

Comment: Reading your message,It looks like your CSV file has different columns on line 6. Just post a part of CSV file here then people will help you out.

Comment: Here is the code of that import tool: https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/blob/89ede1776c60291d75c7286b9e6c406173eb2211/drivers/python/rethinkdb/_import.py#L504

It is clearly compare the number of field in header and number of field of each rows in CSV file. So I guess you have to make up for the extra data, by creating some more empty or NULL field in Mongo DB, export file CSV again, so that the number of field on all rows are equal

Comment: You should probably output as JSON for a much better experience importing into RethinkDB. Is there a reason you went with CSV?

Comment: The size of CSV file is too big (14mb) and hence i am not able to open it on my local machine.However i converted it into JSON format and it worked.I used the following code in my terminal :-                                           rethinkdb import -f out.json --format json --table test.data

Answer (score 0):

There might be better ways of importing data from MongoDB (which is always a good idea). You can use one of the following:

**1. Use Transporter**

Transpoter is a tool to move data from database to database. It has both MongoDB and RethinkDB adapters. I've never used it, but it seems pretty good. It's an open source project by [Compose](http://compose.io).

https://github.com/compose/transporter

**2. Use datda**

This is an npm module I create to do exactly that. It works pretty well expect for some corners cases like date time objects and geometry objects.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/datda

Comment: Very useful tools. OP should just use these directly instead of dealing with MongoDB data CSV exporting. Because RethinkDB prefer JSON http://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/importing/. Using CSV importer make all field as string, which is bad too.

Answer (score 0):

[OP solved problem by exporting from MongoDB as JSON and importing into RethinkDB as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244726/mongodb-csv-export-rethinkdb-csv-import-error#comment52409121_32244726).

```
rethinkdb import -f out.json --format json --table test.data
```